# c#-Windows Form - How find href more link in listbox?

Tags: c#, regex, split, webbrowser-control

www.stackoverflow.com Please check in there lots href="link",

I am just want good solution. How possible received all href link in my listbox.

For example In my site show below like this code.

```
 a href="stackoverflow/questions/31928301/hard-dropping-pieces-in-tetris-like-game" class="question-hyperlink" title="the hard-drop after clearing the ...">tetris-like game
```

```
a href="stackoverflow//questions/31931390/when-i-press-the-button-remove-ads-it-doesnt-do-any-thing-in-in-app-purchases" class="question-hyperlink" title="Can some explain the right code for
```

```
a href="https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199602/will-drinking-ice-cold-water-and-eating-cold-food-cause-weight-loss-over-a-peri" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ item_type:8, target_site:151 }); posts_hot_network .click({ item_type:2, location:8 })">Will drinking ice food cause weight loss (over a period of time)?
```

```
a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222368/get-date-of-next-saturday-from-a-given-date" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ item_type:8, target_site:106 }); posts_hot_network.click({ item_type:2, location:8 })">Get date of next Saturday from a given date
```

Result need collected url only so in my list box show like this

1. http://stackoverflow/questions/31928301/hard-dropping-pieces-in-tetris-like-game
2. http://stackoverflow//questions/31931390/when-i-press-the-button-remove-ads-it-doesnt-do-any-thing-in-in-app-purchases
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222368/get-date-of-next-saturday-from-a-given-date
4. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199602/will-drinking-ice-cold-water-and-eating-cold-food-cause-weight-loss-over-a-peri

bellow code only 1 url getting but how I am received all url?

code

```
  HtmlElementCollection bdColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement bdEl in bdColl)
        {
            if (bdEl.GetAttribute("href").Contains("watch"))

                listBox1 = bdEl.OuterHtml.Split('"')[9];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
HtmlElementCollection bdColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement bdEl in bdColl)
{
     if (bdEl.GetAttribute("href") != null)
                listBox1.Add(bdEl.GetArttribute("href"));
}​
```

Comment: Thanks your Help I am getting good solution from this issue. It's really help my work purpose.